# Autocomplete show an undefined list

Tags: php, jquery, database, autocomplete

I've been working with jQuery UI Autocomplete to make an suggestion from database and autocomplete the rest of field. 
Here is my code.

**HTML :**

```
<form action="#" method="post">
 <p><label for="kdbr">KDBR</label><br />
     <input type="text" name="kdbr" id="kdbr" value="" /></p>
 <p><label for="nmbr">NMBR</label><br />
     <input type="text" name="nmbr" id="nmbr" value="" /></p>
</form>
```

**Javascript :**

```
$(function() {
        //clear values on refresh
        $('#nmbr').val("");

        $("#kdbr").autocomplete({
            source: "<?php echo base_url();?>js/coba3.php",
            minLength: 3,
            select: function(event, ui) {

                $('#nmbr').val(ui.item.nmbr);

            }
        });
    });
```

**PHP :**

```
<?php 
$dbhost = 'HOST';
$dbuser = 'USERNAME';
$dbpass = 'PASSWORD';
$dbname = 'TBNAME';

$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ('Error connecting to mysql');
mysql_select_db($dbname);

$return_arr = array();

/* If connection to database, run sql statement. */
if ($conn)
{
    $fetch = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tb_master_barang where kdbr like '%" .mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['term']) . "%'");

/* Retrieve and store in array the results of the query.*/
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($fetch, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $row_array['kdbr'] = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['kdbr']));
    $row_array['nmbr'] = $row['nmbr'];

    array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
}
}

mysql_close($conn);

echo json_encode($return_arr);
?>
```

The dropdown list show a list of undefined instead value from `kdbr` . I have run the php separately and it returns this value :

```
[{"kdbr":"950.00.0002","nmbr":"PAKAIAN DINAS KS"},{"kdbr":"950.01.0000","nmbr":"BARANG SCURITY LSNG.PAKAI"},{"kdbr":"950.01.0001","nmbr":"PECI"},{"kdbr":"950.01.0002","nmbr":"KOPEL REM HITAM"},{"kdbr":"950.01.0003","nmbr":"SEPATU PDH"},{"kdbr":"950.01.0005","nmbr":"ROMPI SATPAM"},{"kdbr":"950.01.0006","nmbr":"SEPATU PDL"},{"kdbr":"950.01.0007","nmbr":"TALI KOOR & PLUIT"},{"kdbr":"950.01.0008","nmbr":"PAKAIAN TAHAN API"},{"kdbr":"950.01.0009","nmbr":"HELM TAHAN API"},{"kdbr":"950.02.0001","nmbr":"KAOS SCURITI PNJG\/BED\/LOG DLL"}]
```

can someone tell me where i doing wrong?

Comment: Does your javascript is run from php file?

Comment: no, i put the javascript inside `<script>` tags in html part, the php file is being called by javascript for creating json data to make suggestion for autocomplete things

Comment: console.log(ul) and post the log please first in jquery select function

Comment: @AghaUmairAhmed : it returns nothing

Comment: look this example `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11532202/autocomplete-jquery-using-json-data`

Comment: @AghaUmairAhmed : i followed example on that link, but still i got undefined list

Answer (score 0):

Your source field is used in a wrong manner. You need to pass array with data or a anonymous function which will load the data. See the [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp)

Something like this should work:

```
 $("#kdbr").autocomplete({
        source: function (request,  {
            var ajax_url = "<?php echo base_url();?>js/coba3.php?term=" + request.term;

            $.ajax({
                url: ajax_url,
                success: function (response) {
                    // assuming valid json
                    var data = $.parseJSON(response);
                    response($.map(data, function (obj) {
                        return {
                            label: obj.name + ': ' + obj.description,
                            value: obj.name,
                            id: obj.name
                        };
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 3,
        select: function (event, ui) {

            $('#nmbr').val(ui.item.nmbr);

        }
    });
```

Comment: it caused an error : 
`Notice: Undefined index: term`
the term that used in sql query is missing

Comment: I'm not here to write code for you. I've gave you a sample code which is taken from documentation link I've gave, and adapted to your code, there is no way I can test it without actual enviroment. You will need to figure it out yourself. Good luck

Comment: i know it, and still try to figure it out why it was not loaded while trying the possibilities with another answer that have been given, thank you insanebits :)

Comment: the javascript is loaded now, but still return undefined list and inserting an `undefined` value to the field instead of the `kdbr`..still working on it ~

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
  select: function(event, ui) {
          jQuery.get(ui.item.nmbr);
        }
```

Comment: sorry, but the list still showing `undefined` instead of `kdbr`