# Uncaught Type Error - Autocomplete is not a function in ASP.Net

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have seen a number of these questions been asked and it almost always involves having an extra jQuery library or not having referenced the correct ones. I can't see where this related to mine though. The error I get is:

[image]

[image]

I know the script is working as if I do an `alert("Hello World")` it shows. Also the Generic Handler is working as it collects all the parts from the database.

[image]

When I do the hello world call though it appears when the app first loads not when I start to type in the text box? I'm sure this has something to do with it. Maybe it is calling the function before it is loaded but I am not sure why?

Is anyone able to see what is going wrong here?

Comment: Did you combine `autocomplete` when building your custom `jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js` ?

Comment: This is from JQueryUI downloads. http://jqueryui.com/download/#!version=1.10.4&components=1101000000100010000000000000000000I have tried others and they didn't work either.

Comment: Can you check the "view source" in the browser whether the element id is rendered as `txtPartNames` since asp.net will change the id if you haven't used the client id mode as static

Comment: After trying Aruna's suggestion, you could try using one from official > https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js

Comment: @Aruna - presence or absence of a DOM element with `id="txtPartNames"` has nothing to do with the error

Comment: @Danrex - either *jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js* did not load, or it does not contain `autocomplete` plugin

Comment: Also check whether jQuery has been included once or twice?

Comment: @Aruna No it is using txtPartNames

Comment: @Igor It def contains the function just checked. So is there a way to see why it is not loading?

Comment: @KraangPrime Ok tried that but still not working

Comment: I added a solution to demonstrate how to make it work.  Try swapping out your custom UI library / etc with this block instead. Also try swapping `../PartHandler.ashx` with just `/PartHandler.ashx` .  I also noticed that you appended `?term=Calf`.  Make sure that is returning results when nothing is passed. I updated the solution to include a link to another solution which { may | may not } be relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a functional example of it working (bare bones) :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $( function() {
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: [ "ActionScript", "AppleScript", "Asp" ]
    });
  } );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<input id="tags">
```

You might also wish to check out this solution : [AutoComplete jQuery Using JSON data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11532265/3504007)

Comment: Still getting the error.

Comment: then, as @Aruna suggested, you have second jquery.js in your page

Comment: Did you try my suggestions ?  -  replace the `../` part of the path.  Look at the link solution for `term=?` method, and so on.   Also, did you replace the `<script>` stuff with the ones from cdn which are included in the example above.  If you run the sample, it is functional. As Igro and Aruna are pointing out, could also be due to duplicate of script, however it would be further down in the html source.

Comment: I have tried all the solutions. Replaced ../, I have a blank string when term=? returns nothing, and I have replaced the script content. Need to find out where this second jQuery script is but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: The same way you generated the second screenshot showing the html source, you just keep scrolling down.

Comment: So I created a new black ASP web form. Did the above and it works. So I am thinking it might be something to do with the RequiredFieldValidators that I am using? I can see a second call been made.

Comment: @Danrex - glad to hear.  Step through bit by bit and add in the new code (keep using the script references etc as above)  until something breaks.  That should let you know decisively where the or code is broken.

Comment: Indeed it was the ASP validation controls. Do you want to incorporate this into your answer and I will mark it as correct?

Comment: @Danrex - you can edit and add that to the solution, however the original question doesn't contain anything about validation, so to other viewers it would be like pulling something out of thin air.  I recommend update the question to include the offending code.  Glad this helped you resolve the problem :)